# Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\1.3.3.RELEASE\

Tags: spring

My pom.xml is this:
https://hastebin.com/liyetukeze.xml

How it looks like under Eclipse neon.3
[image: How it looks like under Eclipse neon.3]

Comment: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not r (position: START_DOCUMENT seen r... @1:1)  @ C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom, line 1, column 1

Comment: Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
 dependencies\1.3.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.3.3.RELEASE.pom: only whitespace content allowed 
 before start tag and not r (position: START_DOCUMENT seen r... @1:1)